# Creating a signed URL - generated URL is missing signature

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I am very new to using aws-sdk-php and I am trying to create a signed URL for Cloudfront (to an object in a S3 bucket).  My code is as follows (using the aws-sdk-php):

```
function test_cloudfront_signed_url(){
require ABSPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

$cloudFront = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
  'region'  => 'us-west-2',
  'version' => 'latest'
]);

// Setup parameter values for the resource
$resourceKey = 'REDACTED';
$expires = time() + 300;

// Create a signed URL for the resource using the canned policy
$signedUrlCannedPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedUrl([
  'url'         => $resourceKey,
  'expires'     => $expires,
  'private_key' => '/path/to/key/REDACTED.pem',
  'key_pair_id' => 'REDACTED'
]);

echo $signedUrlCannedPolicy;
}
```

A URL is generated but whenever I try to access that URL I always get an error saying the 'Missing Signature query parameter or cookie value'.  Perhaps I am not using the SDK correctly but I am not sure what I could be doing wrong.  My private key is in place.

Most of this code is from what I have found on AWS's own documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging on this I found that it was file permissions on the private key that was stopping the SDK from signing the URL.